# Compile LESS to CSS from command line - Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials

We have a MVC 4.5 app and it has a bunch of LESS files. VS2013/Web Essentials does a fantastic job of compiling the LESS files to CSS as long as I am in VS. We had a new designer join our team and he is not too keen on using VS and I dont blame him. We have psake build scripts that build our project using MSBuild, so we can give him a powershell script to build the application on his machine without opening VS but surprisingly the LESS files are not getting compiled into CSS when built by MSBuild.

Is there any way I can use the same tools that Web Essentials uses to compile the Less files from the command line?

Comment: Did you ever find any kind of solution for this?  I found this article http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2012/11/21/msbuild-task-to-compile-less-files/ which points out how to create a custom msbuild task which I'm going to try.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, use DotLess (http://www.dotlesscss.org/) for build time compiles. I have it compiling our LESS files using a VS post-build event.  Though, guess this could conflict with Web Essentials, not sure who will run last.  Currently not using Web Essentials.